# How to insert opening and closing brackets using regex for this string in R

Tags: json, r, regex, gsub

Hello I have this json entry stored in object string in R:

```
string <- '"rooms":"{\"name\": \"01\",\"type\": \"Quiet Room\",\"used\": \"90\",\"empty\": \"10\"},{\"name\": \"02\",\"type\": \"Meeting Room\",\"used\": \"90\",\"empty\": \"10\"}"}'
```

Would like to insert opening and closing brackets to make it a json array using gsub such that the result is:

```
"rooms": "[{\"name\": \"01\",\"type\": \"Quiet Room\",\"used\": \"90\",\"empty\": \"10\"},{\"name\": \"02\",\"type\": \"Meeting Room\",\"used\": \"90\",\"empty\": \"10\"}]"
```

My current approach:

```
gsub("rooms\":\"\\{\\\"name(.*\\\"\\})\"", "rooms\":\"\\[\\{\\\"name\\1\\]\"", string)
```

But it doesn't work :( Any ideas friends?

Comment: Is it just a pair of brackets, one before the first curly bracket and one at the end?

Comment: yup it is! this is actually part of a longer json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `sub` with this pattern:

```
sub('(.*):\"(.*)}','\\1:"[\\2}]',string)
```

This will insert an open bracket after the first `:\` and a closing bracket after the last `}`.